# Prevent breaking/stopping program on signals within GDB

Tags: gdb, gdbserver, bochs

I've run into a bit of an issue. I'm debugging a BOCHS OS emulator in GDB, and it sends Signal 0 fairly often (every time there is a page fault). I was wondering if there was a way to explicitly tell gdb to not break/stop execution on signals?

I've tried "handle all nostop" and specifically "handle 0 nostop", but it doesn't work.

[image: CLion debugging, always breaks on signal 0]

Let me know if there's any additional information I can provide. I'd consider myself only an intermediate gdb user, so any help is great!

I've read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662810/gdb-catching-a-signal-and-continue-debugging) and [this man page](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Signals.html) but neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to set

```
handle 0 noprint
```

From the man page

> GDB should not mention the occurrence of the signal at all. This implies the nostop keyword as well.

Comment: Unfortunately gdb only lets you `handle` signals 1 - 15, as far as I can tell. https://i.imgur.com/frY75ms.png

Answer (score 0):

If you run info signals in gdb, it gives you a list of signals by name, which works fine with `handle`.

For example:

```
(gdb) handle SIG34 noprint
Signal        Stop  Print   Pass to program     Description
SIG34         No    No      Yes                 Real-time event 34
```